# Newline not executing properly using nasm for x86 architecture

Tags: assembly, newline, nasm, machine-instruction

I am using the instruction `0xa` at the end of a string to create a newline so that the last string printed does not run into the next.

```
mov bx, MESSAGE
call print_string

mov bx, ANOTHER
call print_string

hlt

print_string:
    pusha

    string_loop:
        mov al, [bx]
        cmp al, 0
        jne print_char

        popa
        ret

        print_char:
            mov ah, 0x0e
            int 0x10
            add bx, 1
    jmp string_loop

;global vars
MESSAGE: db 'Example string',0xa,0
ANOTHER: db 'Another example string',0xa,0

;padding/magic number
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The only problem is that, while the strings do indeed print one line below the last, the new line does not reset the x position on the screen, so instead of printing directly below the previous string, it prints below and just after the previous string.

example output:

```
Example string
              Another example string
```

How do I write this code so that strings print directly under the previous string?

Comment: You need to add a `CR` character (0x0d).

Comment: `0xa` is not an instruction, it's data the way you're using it.  If you tried to execute `0x0a` as a byte of machine code, it would [decode as `OR r8, r/m8`](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html#x0A).

Comment: IMO this works sort of by accident. According to this description of [int 10h,e](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-e.html) the `bh` and `bl` are arguments, but you are using `bx` as offset. As your code is very short (end of `ANOTHER` < 256), the `bh` is `0`, and `bl` is colour only in graphics mode, in text mode it's ignored. But I wouldn't recommend such clever trickery without at least comment in code explaining why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to do with Jester's comment (add carriage return alongside linefeed):

```
MESSAGE: db 'Example string',13,10,0
ANOTHER: db 'Another example string',13,10,0
```

What to do with Ped7g's comment (change `BX` into `SI` and setup the `BL` and `BH` arguments):

```
mov bx, 0007h       ;Display page 0, graphics color 7
mov si, MESSAGE
call print_string
...
string_loop:
    mov al, [si]
    ...
    add si, 1
    jmp string_loop
```

---

Since this is bootloader code (`times 510-($-$$) db 0` `dw 0xaa55`) and that ORG 0 is the default, you should best explicitely set the `DS` segment register at zero. Don't trust your executing environment for this!

```
xor     ax, ax
mov     ds, ax
```

Put this before anything else.